# Why jQuery data() is undefined on ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, undefined

I have this link:

```
<div id="prod-interacoes">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-sku="'.$produto.'" data-inte="com" data-status="2">
<div id="int-icon" class="singico icon-inth_COM"></div></a>
</div>
```

and this jQuery/ajax like:

```
$('#prod-interacoes').on('click', '#int-icon',(function(){
    $button = $(this);                          

    var psku = $button.data('sku');
    var inte = $button.data('inte');
    var status = $button.data('status');

    var infos = 'sku=' + psku + '&inte=' + inte + '&status=' + status;
    var link = 'http://linkhere';

  if ($button.hasClass('icon-inth_COM')){               

    // ajax. do unfollow
    $.ajax({                
        type: 'POST',
        url: link,                  
        data:infos,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        etc...
```

Why my response is *undefined* for **psku**, **int** and **status** vars??

I'm new with jscript. Thanks for any help.

---

**CORRECT:**

The data information should be on div and not on link:

```
<div id="prod-interacoes">
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
<div id="int-icon" data-sku="'.$produto.'" data-inte="com" data-status="2"
class="singico icon-inth_COM"></div></a>
</div>
```

Comment: You are not having id attribute of the anchor shown in markup

Comment: Sorry, I forgot, I have. EDIT

Comment: I'm getting: sku: "undefined", inte: "undefined", status: "undefined" when clicked.

Comment: If I make data: 'inte=com&sku=<?php echo $produto;?>&status=1' it works. But I need it as a var, cause I have many different links on same page.

Comment: Yes, the values are on link.

Comment: The target ID is not on the link, it is on the div. The data is on the link not the div. Your click handler is set to activate on the div so `undefined` would be expected

Comment: Wow, that's it! Thank you so much! :) Would you like to make a answer?

Comment: you can pass the data as a js object, like this `data: {sku:psku,inte:inte,status:status}`